# Replace Element in Array does not refresh Angular-Table

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a HTML-Table in Angular. The rows will be propagated like

```
<tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let el of filteredElements;">
    <td align="right">{{el.totalExpenses | number : '.2-2'}}</td>
```

When I refresh an Element in the Array filteredElements, the View is not updated. Here is my code for refreshing the Array:

```
this.filteredElements[this.filteredElements.findIndex(el => el.id === old.id)] = newElement;
```

What do I have to do to update the value in the table in Angular (the table should for example show the new value for totalExpenses).

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript spread operator (...) allows us to quickly copy all or part of an existing array or object into another array or object

```
this.filteredElements = [...this.filteredElements]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `filteredElements` object updated in one component and passed to another component (parent child relations with @Input or something)?

If so, inorder for the angular change detection to be triggered by default, *the entire array needs to be refreshed or repopulated*. Other option would be to *manually trigger the change detection* or *identifying the changes (using OnChanges())* and acting on the change